# How to use ajax in laravel 5.3

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and am using Laravel 5.3. I want to make a text field where it will automatically suggest some data and when I select a data it will add it to an array. I want to send that array to a controller for further use. For this the

> view file is as follows:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var members = {!!  json_encode($member)  !!};
            console.log(members);
            var arr = [];
            $("#tags").autocomplete({
                source: members,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    arr.push(ui);
                    console.log(arr);
                }
            });
            $("#submit").click(function(event){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/storeresearch',
                    data: {selectedMembers: arr},
                    success: function( msg ) {
                        console.log(msg);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="hu" action="/storeresearch" method="POST">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <label>Research Author</label>
    <input type="text" id="tags" name="researchsupervisor_1" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add">
</form>
</body>
```

> My Controller file is as follows:

```
public function store(Request $request){
        if($request->ajax())
        {
            $mem = $request->all();
            return response()->json($mem,200) ;
        }
        else{
            return "not found";
        }
```

> And web.php is as followings:

```
Route::post('/storeresearch','ResearchController@store');
```

But it seems that there is no ajax call happening. In the controller it always enters the else section. What is the problem can anyone help?

Comment: change `<input type="submit">` to `<input type="button">` then try

Comment: Yes it fires the ajax call but the action doesn't occur. It remains in the same page

Comment: That is what ajax stands for. Your page will not refresh when you are dealing with ajax

Comment: Ow Thanks for making the conception clear. But i want both when i hit the button the ajax call and go to the controller that return something. Can you please help me about that how to do?

Comment: exactly what you have to do? clear it.

Comment: Actually i have to get the id o the selected names. The selected names are being passed along with name and id to the autocomplete field. When i am selecting an element the the selected element is being added to the an array i want to pass that array to my controller for further operations when i click the submit button.

Comment: I think this is currently happening. Are you getting any issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem by doing following

```
$.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'your url',
                data:{_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                },
                success: function( msg ) {
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code mostly looks good. But you are missing to send a csrf token with AJAX call as you are using POST request.

You can send csrf token with AJAX call in this way:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

More info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

When you hit the button, does it really fires an AJAX call? Please check that on network tab of browser.

Comment: I have also tried that but no change. And when i hit the button it doesn't fire any ajax call(). :(

Answer (score 2):

Try some thing like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url     : '/login',
    method  : 'post',
    data    : {
        login_username  : userName,
        password        : password
    },
    headers:
    {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    success : function(response){

    }
});
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/login',[
    'uses' => 'AdminServiceController@login'
]);
```

Controller method:

```
 public function login()
{
    $userName   = INPUT::get('login_username');
    $password   = INPUT::get('password');

    // your logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What's your namespace declaration for Request ?

If it is `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` try `use Request;`