# How Can I Use Ajax With Laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

I have the following function in my controller.

```php
public function index()
{
    $number = DB::table('counters')->first();

    return view('app', compact('number'));
}

public function count()
{
    DB::table('counters')->where('id', 1)->increment('number');
}
```

**Routes**

```php
Route::get('/', 'CounterController@index');
Route::get('/count', 'CounterController@count');
```

**View**

```
<a href="{{action('CounterController@count')}}">
    <div class="button lighter-blue" id="form-button-1" data-attribute="1">
    Ja
    </div>
</a>
```

The count function works, but I want to do it with Ajax because I have the number in my view.

```php
<h3>Nummer: {{ $number->number }}</h3>
```

And I want to click on the button and then the number increments, and it shows me directly. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use ajax in laravel 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42154359/how-to-use-ajax-in-laravel-5-3)

Comment: i dont get it, i tried for 3 hours and nothing works :(

Comment: only if i refresh the page it shows me the new number :/ but i want it exactly after click on the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything unusual here - looks like just a standard ajax response.  There are loads of good tutorials out there, such as [this one](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_and_ajax.htm)

But, to answer your question, first make the button a button so that jQuery / js can accept the action rather than having to refresh the page.  Something like:

```
<button id = 'getCount'>Get Count</button>
```

This would replace the whole anchor link above.

Then, catch it in js with the id:

```
$("#getCount").on('click', function(){ 
    // AJAX HERE
}
```

Then your call to get the count that goes within the above onClick (can simplify more, but this shows a clear ajax method - you'll need to tweak for your code):

```
$.ajax({
      url: APP_URL + "/count" ,
      type: "GET",
       success: function (countResult) {
          showResult(countResult)
       },
       error: function () {
         alert ('Problem');
       }
  });
```

I've broken out the display for clarity.  You can add an id to the `<h3>` in order to overwrite:

```
<h3 id='count'>Nummer: {{$number->number}}</h3>
```

Then, your show method can just write in the count:

```
function showResult(count){
    $("#count").text('Nummer '+count);
}
```

You'll need to tweak, but this will get you where you need to be.  Take a look at the tutorial above, that will help you understand where this is going and you can eventually simplify this down.

Comment: but if i do it with javascript i can not increment the number in my database ?

Comment: Why not?  When the ajax hits your controller, it increments the count in the database.  Sorry, I should have added -- you need to *return* the new value that was incremented to the ajax call.  So when the DB updates, get the new count in the controller and return that value back to ajax so that the countResult variable in the ajax success function has the new incremented count.