# 405 (Method Not Allowed) on post method laravel ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I get an 405 (Method Not Allowed) error when sending an AJAX request. I've been working hard looking for a solution but still receive the same error.

I have added this inside the header section:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And this is the AJAX code:

```js
function AjaxCall() {
  var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
  
  $.ajax({
    url: 'insertNum',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    header: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
    },
    data: {
      _token: token,
      _method: "PUT",
    },
    success: function() {
      console.log('success');
    }
  });
}
```

Laravel code:

```php
try {
  $lastNum = DB::table('no_antrian')->select('antrian')->first();

  if (!is_null($lastNum)) 
  {    
    $data = DB::table('no_antrian')->update(['antrian' => $lastNum + 1]);
  }

  return response()->json(['success' => 'Sukses']);
}
catch(\Exception $e) {
  return response()->json(['error' => 'failed']);
}
```

Route:

```
Route::post('antrian/insertNum', [AntrianController::class, 'getQueueNum']);
```

Comment: The error means that the `insertNum` endpoint is not configured to accept POST requests. You need to check your server side logic to correct that

Comment: here my server side logic

Comment: Please click `edit` under the question and add it to the question. Code in comments is almost unreadable

Comment: Maybe you need change `type: 'POST'` with `type: 'PUT'`,

Comment: @Dmitry still same error

Comment: Or you need remove `_method: "PUT",`

Comment: Similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42154359/how-to-use-ajax-in-laravel-5-3

Comment: Also you can change `Route::post('antrian/insertNum', [AntrianController::class, 'getQueueNum']);` with `Route::put('antrian/insertNum', [AntrianController::class, 'getQueueNum']);`

Comment: @Dmitry have changed, get error 500

Comment: @Jemy00 Could you please show the errors?

Comment: @Dmitry PUT http://localhost:8000/antrian/insertNum 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

please Remove put method inside data

```
 var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
 let myData = $('form').find('input[name="my_data"]').val();
  
  $.ajax({
    url: 'insertNum',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      _token: token,
       my_data: myData
    },
    success: function() {
      console.log('success');
    }
  });
```

Comment: still get error 500 (Internal Server Error)